# QT Creator does not recognize STL types for new projects

Tags: c++, qt

I have an existing project where the STL types are recognized. However, when creating a new project none of the STL types are not recognized. For example in

```
#include <string>
string s;
```

the colour of `string`will not change and compilation will generate errors.

Strangly enough when on the include line "Follow symbol under cursor" is executed the include file is opened. So the include file is there, Qt Creator knows how to open it and still class string is not recognized.

Did a reinstall of Qt5.5 but no avail.
What's happening?

Comment: The STL type is called `std::string`, not `string`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
std::string
```

or:

```
using namespace std
```

at the beggining and you will not have to add the namespace every time

Comment: Or, better yet, `using std::string`, unless it's a header file in which case `std::string` is the way.